# Scraping just dial website using google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I tried to scrape just-dial website using google sheet with some degree of success.

This is what i'm trying

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.justdial.com/Gurgaon/Travel-Agents/ct-302", "//span[@class='jcn']/a")
```

It returns me just this

```
Ajay Travels    
Shri Khatu Shyam Ji Tour An..   
Maa Shitla Tour And Travels 
Jbs Travel Solutions    
K K Tours & Travels India P..   
Shri Shyam Tour & Travels   
Instant Corporate Solution  
Sai Ram Tour and Travels    
Ekam Holidays
```

Rest of the information like phone number ,location ,working hour are not returned. There are other ways of parsing using selenium but I haven't used much.

So is it possible to do using google sheet ? Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean ‘scraping’. Scrapping means throwing away.

Comment: pardon my spelling error yes you got my point

Comment: Hi ! When I tried your function it returned the following error : ```Could not fetch url: http://www.justdial.com/Gurgaon/Travel-Agents/ct-302```. Is it working on your end and if so could you please share a sample Spreadsheet without any sensitive data so that I can test your function. Also bear in mind that [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) can only retrieve static data so any data inserted with Javascrpipt wont be possible to be retrieved.

Comment: it did work now as you have reported its not working somehow ...not sure what went wrong ...

Comment: This might be due to the website changing its code. Could you please check again and see if you can find the element you want to retrieve and change the function accordingly to match the updated website? Thanks !

Comment: will update you ..soon